# Как сделать зеленый цвет выбраного option в select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

[image: нужно сделать вот так]

Необходимо, чтобы `option` при наведении был зеленым цветом, и `outline` списка `option` также был зелененьким.

```css
.form-group display: inline-block vertical-align: top overflow: hidden max-width: 100% width: 440px box-sizing: content-box option color: #7e817f box-sizing: content-box filter: hue-rotate(125deg) font-size: 14px!important padding: 10px select max-width: 100% border: none box-sizing: content-box color: #7e817f width: 410px outline: none padding: 12px border: 2px solid #E1E1E1 optgroup font-weight: normal font-style: normal color: #848484 font-size: 14px form-group__house__house display: flex flex-direction: column margin-right: 20px margin-bottom: 23px .custom-select flex-basis: 100% padding: 10px max-width: 500px border-radius: 5px border: 2px solid #E1E1E1 outline: none -webkit-appearance: none -moz-appearance: none appearance: none position: relative
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group__house">
    <label for="my-select">Номер</label>
    <select id="my-select" class="custom-select">
      <optgroup label="-- Выберите номер --">
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="1">Коттедж "Деревенский" 2 этаж</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="2">Дом «Охотника» пн-чт</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="3">Дом «Охотника» пт-вс, праздничные дни</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="4">Дом «Лесника с баней»</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="5">Дом «Рыбака с баней»</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="6">Аренда парной 3 часа</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="7">Аренда парной 4 часа</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="8">Аренда парной 5 часов</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="9">1 этаж коттедж «Уютный»</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="10">2 этаж коттедж «Уютный»</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="11">1 этаж коттедж «Деревенский»</option>
        <option class="custom-select_option" value="12">2 этаж коттедж «Деревенский»</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/andrey-orlov-the-sasster/pen/qBENKbP)

Comment: Насколько я знаю, только CSS в этом случае не обойтись. Посмотрите решение с js на w3 schools . ссылка https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К несчастью отрисовка `option` происходит средствами ОС и отредактировать его на чистом CSS возможностей очень мало. Попробуйте сторонние модули для `jQuery`, например [Form Styler](http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/) или [Select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/). Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/fecs9d9L/) использования первого.